# HashMap created in Main method want to access in other functions

Tags: java, hashmap

I have an hashmap in main and want to access it for another function ?

```
public class SLR{

    public static First(String fst){

        *want to access the entire HashMap here

    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        HashMap<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Added data to mymap

    } 

}
```

Comment: Pass `mymap` as a parameter to `First`

Comment: @MadProgrammer there is another way which is **not good** to have global variable such as a datafiled or something?

Comment: @KickButtowski IMHO - Globals aren't a good choice and should be avoid where possible.  A class field would be a better idea, but we don't have a instance of the class to use them with (everything is `static`) and `static` is just a bad idea/practice which should be avoid at all costs (or at least as much as possible)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I never said it is a good idea. It is good to show the whole picture to the op .

Comment: @KickButtowski Your probably right, but I'm still half asleep ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways you could do this. Preferrably, you might consider using a class instance field, but since you don't have an instance of the class, this won't work here (at least not so far as your code has gone).

You could use a `static` field, but this leads to bad habits which are simply better avoided (`static` is not your friend and it will bury in you pile of problems and issues if not used carefully).

In you case, one of the better solutions is to change the `First` method to take a `Map` as one of the parameters, for example...

```
public class SLR{

    public static First(String fst, Map<String, String> mymap){

        *want to access the entire HashMap here

    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        HashMap<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        First(someString, myMap);

    } 

}
```

This has the benefit of allowing you to use different instances `Map`s but getting repeated/re-usable functionality from the `First` method

You might alos like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

## Example of using a class instance field

```
public class SLR{

    private Map<String, String> mymap;

    public SLR() {
        mymap = new HashMap<String, String>(25);
    }

    public SLR(Map<String, String> map) {
        mymap = map
    }

    public First(String fst){
        mymap.get(...); // or what ever...    
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        SLR slr = new SLR();
        slr.First(someString);

        HashMap<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        SLR otherSrl = new SLR(myMap);
        otherSrl .First(someString);

    } 

}
```

There's not enough context to the question to tell you which you might want to use, you'll need to make that choice yourself

Comment: "There are a number of ways you could do this. " warrants a +1 ;)

Comment: "`static` is not your friend". I disagree. `static` is a great friend, you just need to get to know him better. :P

Comment: @JaredRummler While that is a personal opinion (of mine), `static` causes more issues then it solves, especially in complex, multi tiered solutions, but that's just my experience

Answer (score 0):

Make a class variable if you are not going to instantiate the class, or create a  property/data field and use it after class instantiation.

As others suggested, you can pass the map around as argument as well.

```
public class SLR{
 static Map<string, string> myMap = new HashMap<string, string>();
}
```

Comment: why static? why to be a data field? why not just pass it as an argument ?

Comment: I think you meant "make a static field", and not to stammer "create a create a" ;-)

Comment: @KickButtowski You can do that too. Developers choice.

Comment: @Andreas the answer must cover the whole aspect of the issue as much as it can not just one portion of it

Comment: @KickButtowski Agreed, and Jerome did edit the answer. But if that was your intent, your comment came off wrong. "why not just" implies his answer was wrong. Instead suggest an expansion of the answer.

Comment: @Andreas Madprogrammer covers them all ;)

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `HasMap` as a parameter to the function `First()` seems to solve your problem.

```
public class SLR {

public static void First(HashMap<String, String> map, String fst){
    //Here you have full access to the content of your HashMap
    //doSomething();
}

public static void main (String[] args){

    HashMap<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    First(mymap, someString);//Pass the map as a parameter

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

By creating class variable:

```
public class SLR{

    static HashMap<String, String> myMap;
    public static First(String fst){

        // your code

    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        myMap= new HashMap<String, String>();

        //Added data to mymap



    } 

}
```

Passing map as param:

```
public class SLR{

    public static First(String fst,HashMap<String, String> mymap){

        // your code

    }

    public static void main (String[] args){

        HashMap<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Added data to mymap
        // call "First" method

    } 

}
```